# Do we need to make it easier to find out what colours mean on SO?

Tags: feature-request, design, hyperlinks

I've been puzzling for a while about why some questions are listed with a "creme" background instead of white, and other such things, but couldn't find a definitive guide to what things like this are intended to communicate on SO.

Then, after searching meta SO, I found some of the answers, and by following an onward trail, I found a lot of great info buried in [this meta StackExchange question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean). Do we need a link from SO pages to this kind of guide?

Answer (score 2):

That's a Stack Overflow specific FAQ. Other Stack Exchanges probably have slightly different color schemes (like Meta Stack Exchange itself).

It should be migrated back over to Meta Stack Overflow, instead of staying on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: Be that as it may, shouldn't we make it easier to find this kind of info without searching questions other baffled users have asked on a meta site?

Comment: @RegEdit: Certainly. We should also make it easier to find answers to all questions without having to search to find out what other users have asked before, at the entire SE network. Oh, wait. That won't work, will it? We'd probably need, umm, a search capability to locate those results?